# Got issue debugging code The currently targeted framework .NETFRAMEWORK, Version =v4.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-3.5

I am working on ASP.NET application based on .NET Framework version 3.5 on visual studio 2013 and when I debug code I got following warning message

```
Warning 708 The currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" does not include "System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which the referenced assembly "C:\Users\kzahid\Desktop\ADB Project\My Development\13.023-PSMD-Startup-master\13.023-PSMD-Startup-master\Applications\ORC.PCMD.ADB\ORC.PCMD.BLL\bin\Debug\ORC.PCMD.ADB.BLL.dll" depends on. This caused the referenced assembly to not resolve. To fix this, either (1) change the targeted framework for this project, or (2) remove the referenced assembly from the project.    ObjectTester
```

[image]

From project properties, its confirm that .NET Framework version is 3.5 but I am not sure why I am getting following error!

Comment: You should change your reference to `System.Web` from v4.0 to v2.0.  Just remove this dll from list of references and add it again.

Comment: I have removed ORC.PCMD.ADB.BLL from ORC.PCMD.ADB.UI references and add it again but still got same error

Comment: Many Thanks for help, it works!

Comment: Glad to hear it. Your `ORC.PCMD.ADB.BLL` confused me. Tried to find out :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried cleaning the solution, changing the version to 4.0, save, then change it back to 3.5 and rebuild? I've seen some weird things like this from time to time with Visual Studio where sometimes it seems like it hangs onto old settings for some reason.